# Correcting SQL using SET in MySQL to display

Tags: mysql, sql, set

ITrying to get 2 separate select statements to show in one result set using a user defined variable. Should I use a Union or With somewhere here?

```
﻿SET @X1 = 
((SELECT SUM(ef.Fee * (rd.ActualReturn - ra.startdate)) as "total revenue from rentals"
FROM EqRentDetails as rd
JOIN EquipmentInventory  as ei ON rd.ItemSKU = ei.ItemSKU
JOIN EqRentAgreement as ra ON rd.RentalID = ra.RentalID
JOIN customers ON customers.CustomerID = ra.CustomerID
JOIN EquipmentFee as ef ON ef.EquipmentID = ei.EquipmentID and customers.CategoryKey = 
ef.Customercategory
WHERE rd.Actualreturn IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY ra.CustomerID));


SET @Y =
(SELECT SignUp.ParticipantID, SUM(avt.TripFee) as "Total revenue from trip fees"
FROM SignUp
JOIN Offerings as o on o.OfferingCode = SignUp.OfferingCode
JOIN AvailableTrips as avt on avt.TripID = o.TripCode
JOIN Customers on Customers.CustomerID = SignUp.ParticipantID
group by SignUp.ParticipantID);

#for display

Select @Y, @X;
```

Comment: your first select returns one row per ra.CustomerID and your second returns one row per SignUp.ParticipantID; how do these relate?   show some example data and expected results for that data.  no, you should not use user defined variables (which in any case will not work when you have more than one row).

Comment: I tried this and get an empty result set because I don't have the data loaded but it seems to run.

Comment: As soon as you have multiple ra.CustomerID or SignUp.ParticipantID this will give an error

Answer (score 0):

```
Create View Customer_total_rental_rev AS
((SELECT customers.CustomerID, SUM(ef.Fee * (rd.ActualReturn - ra.startdate)) as 
"total revenue from rentals"
FROM EqRentDetails as rd
JOIN EquipmentInventory  as ei ON rd.ItemSKU = ei.ItemSKU
JOIN EqRentAgreement as ra ON rd.RentalID = ra.RentalID
JOIN customers ON customers.CustomerID = ra.CustomerID
JOIN EquipmentFee as ef ON ef.EquipmentID = ei.EquipmentID and 
customers.CategoryKey = ef.Customercategory
WHERE rd.Actualreturn IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY ra.CustomerID)) ;

#UNION;

CREATE View Participant_Trip_Rev AS
(SELECT SignUp.ParticipantID, SUM(avt.TripFee) as "Total revenue from trip fees"
FROM SignUp
JOIN Offerings as o on o.OfferingCode = SignUp.OfferingCode
JOIN AvailableTrips as avt on avt.TripID = o.TripCode
JOIN Customers on Customers.CustomerID = SignUp.ParticipantID
group by SignUp.ParticipantID);

Select Customer_total_rental_rev.*, Participant_Trip_Rev.*
 from Customer_total_rental_rev, Participant_Trip_Rev;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can just add the two queries in a single **Select** statement. This way you can reduce some extra SQL code execution. Most of the case it does not matter but some cases it may work as optimization. Here is a sample

```
SELECT
  (SELECT SUM(ef.Fee * (rd.ActualReturn - ra.startdate)) as "total revenue from rentals"
   FROM EqRentDetails as rd
   JOIN EquipmentInventory as ei ON rd.ItemSKU = ei.ItemSKU
   JOIN EqRentAgreement as ra ON rd.RentalID = ra.RentalID
   JOIN customers ON customers.CustomerID = ra.CustomerID
   JOIN EquipmentFee as ef ON ef.EquipmentID = ei.EquipmentID and customers.CategoryKey = ef.Customercategory
   WHERE rd.Actualreturn IS NOT NULL
   GROUP BY ra.CustomerID) AS 'total revenue from rentals',
  (SELECT SUM(avt.TripFee) as "Total revenue from trip fees"
   FROM SignUp
   JOIN Offerings as o ON o.OfferingCode = SignUp.OfferingCode
   JOIN AvailableTrips as avt ON avt.TripID = o.TripCode
   JOIN Customers ON Customers.CustomerID = SignUp.ParticipantID
   GROUP BY SignUp.ParticipantID) AS 'Total revenue from trip fees';
```